# User password creation in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, centos

I want to create a user and set a password for him.
First password line and second one in user module doesnt work. Tried to pass it via hash variable, but no luck :)

If I run [image]

and place value into the password line - it works just fine, still i'd like to use my password variable. Can you kindly show the way how i can send its value into this command?

```
"password | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"
```

.

```
---

 - name: create ssh keys and distribute ssh public key for user
   hosts: clients
   become: yes

   vars:
    uname : Jim
    create_user : False
    password : imuser

   tasks:

   - name: creating password
     set_fact:
        hash : "{{ 'password' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"

   - debug:
       msg : "hashed password is {{ hash }}"

   - name: create user if necessary
     user:
      name: "{{ uname }}"
      state: present
      password : "password | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"
#      password : "{{ hash }}"
#      password: $6$mysecretsalt$ZfUPIwkf1o9u8P04aJuQCgMfSZoIAeCoZpkbNKKn7LtiI.nQl8UWRIhO.rStaZzM8u0Bja3/9bzgOjagM5whY.
      shell : /bin/bash
     when: create_user == "True"

   - name: get etc/passwd
     shell: cat /etc/passwd
     register: passwd

   - block:
     - debug:
         var: passwd.stdout
     - debug:
         var: uname

     when: inventory_hostname == "ansible_client1"

   - name: create ssh key for user
     user:
      name: "{{ uname }}"
      generate_ssh_key : yes
      ssh_key_file : '{{ uname }}_id_rsa'
     when: '"uname" in passwd.stdout'
     register: create_key

   - debug:
       var: create_key
```

And the second question is:

Somehow task "create ssh key for user" is being skipped on ansible_client1 each run after i have deleted the user with userdel and his homedir with rm -rf since it looked weird at first runs of playbook. It works perfectly on 2nd host.
If i check /etc/passwd - user exist for both servers:

```
[admin@ansible_client1 ~]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep Jim
Jim:x:1004:1005::/home/Jim:/bin/bash

[admin@ansible_client2 Jim]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep Jim
Jim:x:1007:1008::/home/Jim:/bin/bash
```

User is being created each time on ansible_client1 and homedir is there, still task is being skipped and it looks like uname cannot be found in passwd.stdout somehow.

So... what's might be going on here i wonder

Comment: Actually this is a text copypaste from MS One Note, should be text, seems somehow it is recognized as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second task you have `"password | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"` it must be `"{{ password | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"` to use use te var `password`  or `"{{ 'password' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"` to use the word `password` as password.

Comment: Got it, thanks Gary ! Seems i was too sleepy to see that :)))